# MYSQL - JOIN table filter not working

Tags: mysql, join

I have four table each table connected with some id kindly see the below query how I'm getting

```
SELECT 
tax_rates.name, 
IF( products.tax_method = 0, 'Inclusive', 'Exclusive') AS type, 
IF((SUM(purchases.grand_total) > 0),(SUM(purchases.grand_total)),(SUM(purchase_items .subtotal))) AS total_amount, 
IF((SUM(purchases.order_tax) > 0),(SUM(purchases.order_tax)),SUM(purchase_items .item_tax)) AS tax_amount 
FROM tax_rates 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.order_tax_id = tax_rates.id 
LEFT JOIN purchase_items ON purchase_items.tax_rate_id = tax_rates .id 
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = purchase_items.product_id 
WHERE purchases.warehouse_id = 1 
GROUP BY tax_rates.id, products.tax_method 
ORDER BY tax_rates.name desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

The above query didn't return any result but if I remove WHERE purchases.warehouse_id = 1  then it display the result. I don't know where I'm doing the mistake. Kindly correct me.

Sorry to tell about this I'm try to get purchase order tax and purchase Item tax
in particular store and date

Output

```
name       type     total_amount    tax_amount 

VAT @20%   Inclusive    11005.2000  1834.2000
VAT @10%   Inclusive    165.0000    15.0000
No Tax     Exclusive    204771.4000     0.0000
GST @6%    Exclusive    7155.0000   405.0000
GST @6%    Inclusive    7155.0000   405.0000
```

Thank you

Comment: Change 'WHERE' to 'AND'

Answer (score 0):

Data type? purchases.warehouse_id = '1'?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the condition in where clause, when you are using the field of the left join table. so remove the where clause and use like below

```
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.order_tax_id = tax_rates.id and purchases.warehouse_id = 1
```

If you try to add the left join table field in where clause it will become INNER JOIN. hence it may not display any rows according to your data.